# (Java) if statement optimization

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jax-rs, sonarqube

Need to optimize this code :

`import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.ws.rs.CookieParam;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
...

private String valueParam(Annotation a) {

    String value = "";

    if (a.annotationType() == QueryParam.class) {
        value = ((QueryParam) a).value();
    } else if (a.annotationType() == PathParam.class) {
        value = ((PathParam) a).value();
    } else if (a.annotationType() == CookieParam.class) {
        value = ((CookieParam) a).value();
    } else if (a.annotationType() == HeaderParam.class) {
            value = ((HeaderParam) a).value();
    } else if (a.annotationType() == MatrixParam.class) {
            value = ((MatrixParam) a).value();
    } else if (a.annotationType() == FormParam.class) {
            value = ((FormParam) a).value();
    }

    return value;
 }`

SonarQube complains about the complexity of this method.

It's not so easy to change because we need to check the annotation type before getting its value!

Note : The trap is on the Annotation interface that doesn't have a value() method.

P.S. : This code based on this [example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam) (Code Example 4)

Comment: Why not use a switch? Build a switch around the annotationType with a case for each class

Comment: @Trobbins I believe SONAR would still complain after using switch.

Comment: Is reflection an option perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If reflection is an option, you can always do something like

```
public class Test {

    @PathParam("path")
    public Response doSomething() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = Test.class.getMethod("doSomething");
        Annotation annotation = method.getAnnotations()[0];
        System.out.println(getValue(annotation));
    }

    private static String getValue(Annotation annotation) throws Exception {
        Class<?> type = annotation.annotationType();
        if (!ANNOTATIONS.contains(type)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        String value = (String) type.getMethod("value").invoke(annotation);
        return value;
    }

    private static final Set<Class<?>> ANNOTATIONS;

    static {
        Set<Class<?>> annotations = new HashSet<>();
        annotations.add(HeaderParam.class);
        annotations.add(QueryParam.class);
        annotations.add(PathParam.class);
        annotations.add(MatrixParam.class);
        annotations.add(CookieParam.class);
        annotations.add(FormParam.class);
        ANNOTATIONS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(annotations);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was looking for. Just I do not throw IllegalArgumentException, just need to return ""